# How to check every contents that I copied

Tags: clipboard

When I click "clipboard button" in android keyboards, I can easily check what I've copied in the past. Also, when I click "Window + v" key in windows 10, I can check the clipboard. How can I check clipboard on ubuntu? If there is, then is it possible to set keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest installing the [Clipboard Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/) extension.

It will add an icon in the "tray" area of the top bar; clicking on the icon will give you a list of your clipboard history. You can customize this, including how much of your history is retained.

By the way, you can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> to toggle the history list, or you can change this to another key combination to match what you are used to in other operating systems.